# Cocoa Pods No header file found for local pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I was testing the use of a podfile i am working on by doing the following ...

In my application i added the pod

pod "SampleSDK" , :local=>pod "SampleSDK", :local=>"~/Documents/Dev/iOS/MobSample"

and my pod spec file is as follows

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "SampleSDK"
  s.version      = "1.0.2"
  s.summary      = "This is an Objective-C SDK for Sample."
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/Sample/SampleSDK.git"

  s.source          = { :git => "https://github.com/Sample/SampleSDK.git",:tag => "v1.0.2"}
  s.public_header_files = 'SampleSDK-iosuniversal/SampleSDK.framework/Headers/*.h'
  s.preserve_paths    = SamplekSDK-iosuniversal/SampleSDK.framework'
  s.frameworks =  'Foundation', 'QuartzCore' , 'SystemConfiguration'
  s.xcconfig = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/SampleSDK/Headers"', 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -all_load -ObjC' }
end
```

pod spec validation is passed 
but when i do pod install no header files are present in LocalPods>>SampleSDK>>

Where am i going wrong? How should i proceed further?

Answer (score 4):

The `public_header_files` is a positive filter of the `source_files`. In this case as all the headers are public you could replace the former with the later and the podspec should work as expected.

Comment: Podspec failed when i tried source_files with the error message that ERROR | The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.

Comment: I would check the pattern. That attribute is used by the majority of the 1515 Pods that we have and is working correctly.

Comment: Btw, I assume `pod "SampleSDK" , :local=>pod "SampleSDK", :local=>"~/Documents/Dev/iOS/MobSample"` to be a typo error.It should be something like `pod "SampleSDK", :local=>"~/Documents/Dev/iOS/MobSample"
`

Comment: it was a typo! And yes i figuring out the correct pattern. Thanks :)

Comment: What's a "positive filter" as opposed to a "negative" one?

Comment: @fatuhoku It means that `public_header_files` is a subset of `source_files`.

Answer (score 0):

If that's actually what your `Podfile` looks like that is the issue. As shown in the [documentation](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod) the purpose of the `:local` key is to allow you to point to the source of a library locally, <del>while also using a podspec that's already part of the [master repo](http://github.com/cocoapods/specs).</del> *Update*: Fabio pointed out to me that as it says in the docs the `:local` option does actually expect the the `podspec` in the folder as well.